# Which classification model should I use for author attribution in machine learning?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, text-classification

I aim to have a train set of texts written by a specific author and a larger test set of unknown texts. I want to be able to predict whether or not each text (or class) in the test set was written by the specific author of the train set of texts. What classification model should I use to achieve this and how might I implement it?

Comment: How many authors and texts do you have in data? Do you have any extra data from the authors?
A group of writers has a style in writing. By this assumption, you could cluster authors to a few groups and then try to classify each text into those groups.

Comment: I have 1 author with an unknown amount of texts. What mode should I use?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a logistic regression model. Even it has "regression" in the name, it is applied to classification.

If the use of certain words is typical for your author, you could create a model that is based on frequency of words in the texts:

- Before you apply the model, you need to create numerical values out of the texts. Therefore you can assign tokens to the unique words.
- You create a feature vector by counting the frequency of the words

[Logistic regession model for text classification](https://github.com/rasbt/python-machine-learning-book-3rd-edition/tree/master/ch08) contains code where these steps are executed in order to derive the judgement of a movie review.

If for example the sequence of words needs to be considered, you need a modified approach.